# Bind ulong value to canvas.width(double) in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement mvvm in wpf application... I am calculating canvas width dynamically in ViewModel. And I want to bind this value to Canvas.width in xaml file. by default, Canvas.width takes double values.. But my calculated value is of type ulong. And I do not want to cast it to double. I want to save the ulong value. Could you please guide me how to bind this.?

Comment: Didn't you try it? It should work out of the box. The Binding performs the type conversion automatically. However, there is nothing wrong with double.

Comment: If it doesn't work directly from binding, try using a converter.

Comment: thanks. I was unaware that binding automatically does type conversion for us.